# Count if date is between a list of date ranges - Google Sheets

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, countif

i'm wondering how to make a formula work to count the times a specific date is between a range of dates but in a list of ranges in google sheets, i'll try to explain this below:

In cell **A1** i have a formated date ( the date i want to find between a range of dates), the range of dates are setup as follows: Start Date: **E1** | End Date: **G1**

So if **A1** is between **E1** and **G1** i need it to be counted, but also i need to count if **A1** is between **E2** and **G2**, and then between **E3** and **G3**, and so on (a list of date ranges)

I'm not sure if this is posible, and really hope you understand what i'm trying to do.

PD: I tried something like this, but with no luck:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1; ">="&E1:E100; A1; "<="&G1:G100)
```

PD2: Link to sheet with example of how i need the formula to work:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1txw0tqo_XrwC5o3QSNSZynsZzIFuf1-xqgQlurUiL00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((A1>=E1:E)*(A1<=G1:G); 1; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This worked great!, i just had to change the separator from "," to ";" i'm not sure if this is because of a setting of google sheets (probably), also, i'm trying to understand how does this works, the array formula, is adding with the conditional of comparing a date between a range of dates, and assings a value of 0 or 1 depending if true or false, what's the * doing there? i don't get it.

Comment: * is logical expression which means AND because regular AND is not supported in arrayformula. eg. if(true*true=true, 1, 0)